# Equal spacing between pie charts of different sizes in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pie-chart

I am having difficulties with setting an equal space between pie charts of different sizes. The 5 are correctly arranged in one row, but the distance between the contours of neighboring pies aren't equal. I tried many abbreviations of the following code, all of them not making a big difference in the output (see image):

#code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
labels = 'Verkehr', 'Maschinen und Motoren', 'Feuerungen', 'Industrie / Gewerbe', 'Land- und Forstwirtschaft'
sizesax1 = [108295, 10107, 7220, 11551, 7220]
sizesax2 = [77882, 6676, 6676, 13351, 6676]
sizesax3 = [55652, 4417, 6184, 15900, 6184]
sizesax4 = [36327, 2642, 4632, 16512, 5944]
sizesax5 = [18781, 1409, 3287, 1878, 4695]

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5) = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize =(20,4))
ax1.pie(sizesax1, startangle=0, colors = ('red', 'darkblue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'), radius=1*4)
ax2.pie(sizesax2, startangle=0, colors = ('red', 'darkblue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'), radius=.77*4)
ax3.pie(sizesax3, startangle=0, colors = ('red', 'darkblue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'), radius=.61*4)
ax4.pie(sizesax4, startangle=0, colors = ('red', 'darkblue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'), radius=.46*4)
ax5.pie(sizesax5, startangle=0, colors = ('red', 'darkblue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'), radius=.33*4)
```

some additions i tried:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=1, hspace=None)
```

or

```
fig.tight_layout()
#giving me this error message:
/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:17: UserWarning:
Tight layout not applied. The bottom and top margins cannot be made large enough to
accommodate all axes decorations.
```

and some others.

Big thank you already for reading this! I am a complete beginner in python and just managed to come as far as you see in this image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMQwA.png)

Comment: This is a little bit poorly defined.  Do you want the whitespace to be the same between pies, or do you want the centers the same distance from each other?  Also how exact do the radii need to be?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what it is required. I'll assume it is the following image:

[image]

Fundamentally, the problem is that the pie needs a square aspect ratio, which is not provided by a row of subplots.

The simplest solution, is to create only one plot and plot there multiple pies with different centres. Something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sizes = [ [108295, 10107, 7220, 11551, 7220],
          [77882, 6676, 6676, 13351, 6676],
          [55652, 4417, 6184, 15900, 6184],
          [36327, 2642, 4632, 16512, 5944],
          [18781, 1409, 3287, 1878, 4695]]

colors = ('red', 'darkblue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green')

R = 4

radius = [R*i for i in [1.0, 0.77, 0.61, 0.46, 0.33] ]
wid = sum(radius)*2
hei = R*2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(wid,hei))
fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0, right = 1, bottom = 0, top = 1)

y = R
x = 0

for i in range(5):

    x += radius[i]
    ax.pie(sizes[i], startangle = 0, colors = colors,
           radius = radius[i], center = (x,y) )
    x += radius[i]

ax.set(xlim =(0,x), ylim=(0,R*2))

plt.savefig("aaa.png")
```

Notice that my figure aspect ratio is not the (20,4) of the question, which does not hold for the way I interpreted the intended result.

But it might be the case that there is the need of having these in different axes. If so, the idea is:

1. Use gridspec to create a single row with 5 columns and provide the ratios so that they correspond to the required radius.
2. Plot the larger pie in the left slot.
3. In all remaining slots, use a subgrid, dividing into a column of three (sub-)slots.
4. Set the height ratios so that the middle one ends up with an aspect ratio of a square.
5. Plot the pies in the middle slots.

Here we go:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sizes = [ [108295, 10107, 7220, 11551, 7220],
          [77882, 6676, 6676, 13351, 6676],
          [55652, 4417, 6184, 15900, 6184],
          [36327, 2642, 4632, 16512, 5944],
          [18781, 1409, 3287, 1878, 4695]]

colors = ('red', 'darkblue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green')

R = 4

radius = [R*i for i in [1.0, 0.77, 0.61, 0.46, 0.33] ]
wid = sum(radius)*2
hei = R*2
ratios = [i/radius[0] for i in radius] # for gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize =(wid,hei))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 5,
                      width_ratios = ratios,
                      wspace=0, left = 0, right = 1, bottom = 0, top = 1)

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax.pie(sizes[0], startangle = 0, colors = colors, radius = 1 )
ax.set(xlim=(-1,1) ,ylim=(-1,1))
    
for i in range(1,5):

    mid = ratios[i]/sum(ratios)*wid
    inrat = [(hei-mid)/2, mid, (hei-mid)/2]
    ings = gs[0,i].subgridspec(3, 1, hspace=0,
                               height_ratios = inrat)
    
    ax = fig.add_subplot(ings[1,0])
    ax.pie(sizes[i], startangle = 0, colors = colors, radius = 1 )
    ax.set(xlim=(-1,1), ylim=(-1,1))

plt.savefig("aaa.png")
```